# Is it possible to find out dependent tables for a view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Apparently, one of my views is not responding to any SQL queries. I was wondering if there is a way to find out what tables this view depends on so that I can debug the problem.

I am not an admin on the server so I wouldn't be surprised if this is not possible in the first place but a confirmation would be great. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just look at the definition of the view

One way (fixed)

```
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID(N'myview'))
```

This is subject to ["metadata visibility"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113.aspx) of course and permissions

Comment: Is this always working regardless of user permissions? http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1593

Comment: Thank You. When I use this it complains: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'viewname' to data type int.` Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try SELECT object_definition (OBJECT_ID(N'myview'))

Comment: Yes just tried it after you posted a link on mssqltips.com. It returns a `NULL` which is probably to say that I don't have permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You should get an error message like the one below, if you try the query from Management Studio

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'table_missing'.
Msg 4413, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Could not use view or function 'view_name' because of binding errors.
```

Comment: Thank You. I am able to query it except that it never finishes or throws an error similar to `OLE DB Provider "SQLCLI10" for linked server "..." returned message "Query Timeout expired"` and I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Increase the query timeout for linked server http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186839(v=SQL.100).aspx

Comment: I tried it but it complains `Alter failed`. Guess I need to contact my DB admin.

Comment: Check also the microsoft knowledge base http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314530/en-us

Answer (score 1):

Although not infallible, you could start with [sp_depends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189487%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Guess this is out of the list of possibilities for me as when I start the PowerShell, it throws a bunch of permission denied messages. But thank you anyways.