# Return view FROM clause using only tsql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way using TSQL to return the FROM section of an existing view?

I know I can get the whole of the view definition with sp_helptext and can get the list of columns either with sp_help or by selecting from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE, but what I'm looking for are the tables and join clauses.

Currently, I'm dumping the return from sp_helptext into an nvarchar(max), and doing a charindex search for 'from '.  I loop through checking to make sure the number of open parentheses equals the number of close parentheses (to factor out subqueries in the select), and if it doesn't I search for the next instance of 'from '.

But I expect this solution is far from bulletproof, and would think there's some built in procedure or systable where I can get this.

The code I'm currently using is as follows...

```
    declare @from int = 1
    declare @newJoin nvarchar(max)
    if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') is not null
    begin
        drop table #t
    end
    create table #t(
    LineId int identity(1,1),
    Text nvarchar(max)
    )

    insert into #t (Text) exec sys.sp_helptext <view_name>

    set @newJoin = ''
    select @newJoin = @newJoin + Text 
    from #t
    where LEFT(LTRIM(replace(Text,char(9),' ')),2)<>'--'
    order by LineId

    while @from > 0
        begin
              SET @from = CHARINDEX('from ', @newJoin, @from + 5)
              IF LEN(REPLACE(LEFT(@newJoin,@from),'(','')) = LEN(REPLACE(LEFT(@newJoin,@from),')','')) BREAK
        end

    set @newJoin = substring(@newJoin, @from + 5, len(@newJoin))
```

Comment: If you are looking for ultimately the tables not the from clause this might help:[Dependent Tables for a View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841250/is-it-possible-to-find-out-dependent-tables-for-a-view)

Comment: Thanks, but I really need the full FROM clause with the join syntax.  The ultimate goal is to create a new view using dynamic SQL with a modified select, but keeping all of the join logic intact.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the system tables might help:

```
select distinct t.name from sys.tables t
inner join sys.sysdepends d on t.object_id = d.depid
where object_id = object_id('<view_name>')
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need the join logic as well.